# Different between (re) and (?: re) - Regular Expression in Java

Tags: java, regex

First at all, I sorry about my English.
I tried to get number in an expression one by one, so I use regular expression.
I used 2 ways to get the number behind "." . I read the documentary before but they are so difficult to understand. So what is different between ( re) and (?: re).Thanks for reading

```
public static void main(String[] args){ 

    String input = ("1123+4+5*1-31.3");
        Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)");
        Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(input);
        while(matcher.find()){
                System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
}

public static void main(String[] args){ 

    String input = ("1123+4+5*1-31.3");
        Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)");
        Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(input);
        while(matcher.find()){
                System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
}
```

Comment: `()` is a capturing group, while `(?:)` is a non-capturing group.

Comment: For example, methods of `Matcher` such as [group()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group(java.lang.String)) work on capturing groups, and will ignore non-capturing groups.

Comment: so the expression inside () and (?:) work the same way?, and only relate about group()?

Comment: @MinhNguyen Correct. Only difference is whether the text matched by the group is *captured*. The captured text can then be retrieved using `group(int)`, and/or used in back-references in the pattern (`\1`, `\2`, ...), and/or as values in the replacement string (`$1`, `$2`, ...). If you don't need captured text, the non-capturing group is preferred, so the regex engine doesn't waste time capturing the text, but more importantly doesn't mess up the group numbers of needed capturing groups, though when no capturing is needed, the capturing group is used, for convenience of the simpler syntax.

Comment: @Andreas Quote: "...though when no capturing is needed, the capturing group is used, for convenience of the simpler syntax." Maybe some people do that, but they shouldn't. `(?:)` explicitly communicates that grouping is required, which facilitates a better understanding of the expression. On the other hand, a capturing group that is purely used for grouping, raises undue questions about if and how captures are employed in- or outside the expression. /Steps off soapbox.